# .NET Reflection - declare variable of type MethodInfo.ReturnType

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, reflection, methodinfo

I'am using reflection for make a call to WCF service:

```cs
var client = new CommonServiceClient();
var thisType = client.GetType();
var theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(methodName);
var resultType = theMethod.ReturnType;
resultType result = theMethod.Invoke(client, parameters.Select(param => param.Value).Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

So, i want that local `result` be a type of `resultType`, but this code produce intelliSense 
error 'cannot resolve symbol resultType'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do this. Your options as I see it are:

1. Continue to use reflection on your result object.
2. If you know that all possible result types are from common base class or share an interface then you can cast to that and use it's methods and properties.